# .Net 4.5.1 <probing privatePath="bin" /> not found

Tags: c#, .net, dll, system.data.sqlite, csc

I am trying to place the sqlite DLL's in a subdirectory relative to my project root.
When the DLL's are placed in the root, the application runs successfully.
When they are placed in ./bin, with an App.config that contains:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
        
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas=microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="bin" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and compiled using:

```
csc /r:bin\System.Data.SQLite.dll /lib:bin /appconfig:App.config /nologo App.cs
```

I receieve the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.118.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at App.Main(String[] args)
```